# How to join a SQL (Teradata) query with time condition?

Tags: sql, database, join, left-join, teradata

I am trying to capture every single email including today until the next day morning at 10.30 AM.  I know I to have add logic on my join and I am not sure I am doing it correctly. Can you anybody please tell is this correct or is there any better way to do it?

what I try to add to the JOIN

```
LEFT JOIN events  b ON a.signup_dt BETWEEN b.mst_dt  AND  b.mst_dt +1 AND Extract(HOUR From  b.mst_dt+1) <= 9 
AND a.email_address = b.email_address
```

Date from event (I have email address column that I did not include here) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMPZ4.png)

Date from Ops table ( I have datetime colunm called signup_dttm)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRTzh.png)

**Clarification -**  On my ops table I have all the emailed captures for the particular date.  We will send a info email for every email we captured from Ops table. That data (Which is email we send in Ops table and date and time) stored in event table. For example we captured 500 emails yesterday(12/11/2019). Then we have send 400 info emails yesterday. Other 100 emails that left we will send it today (12/12/19) sometime before 10.30 AM .  Again those send data will store in event table. That is why I am trying capture everything from yesterday to today 9.00 AM and join to the ops table. Hopefully this will make sense if not please let me know. Any help will highly appreciated.

Thank you so much

Comment: Not sure I follow everything here, but I think you will need to use an OR to handle your 2 dates.  The way you have it now, you are limiting it to <= 9AM for both days. I think you want something like ...`AND (signup_dt = b.mst_dt OR (a.signup_dt = b.mst_dt + 1 and extract(hour...))`

Comment: @Andrew thank yo so much for the comment. So does this logic give me this, for example yesterday to today morning 9 am. What i mean by dynamic dates between 12/11/19 to 12/12/19 9.00 AM?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. The way you currently have it, you would only get everything before 9AM on the 11th and before 9AM on the 12th. Unless I misunderstood, you want every on the 11th and everything before 9AM on the 12th.

Comment: @Andrew thanks I want everything on the 11th and everything before 9 AM on 12th. Does this works? So sorry if I confused you. If this is correct please put as answer so i can select it. Thanks you so much for the help

Comment: @Andrew i want it other way. I want everything on 11th and everything before 9 am on 12th. Sorry for the confusion. How do i do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `INTERVAL` for your join condition:

```
a.signup_dt BETWEEN 
  CAST(b.mst_dt AS TIMESTAMP(0)) AND -- Current day
  (CAST(b.mst_dt AS TIMESTAMP(0)) + INTERVAL '1 09' DAY TO HOUR) -- 9am next day
```

Comment: If it was a DATE you need to cast it to a TIMESTAMP, you can't add HOURs to a DATE. And it must be a two-digit hour: `INTERVAL '1 09' DAY TO HOUR`

Comment: You're right, I had it initially in there as a timestamp but then re-read the initial post and took out the CAST. Will modify, thanks.

Comment: @ravioli Thank you so much for the help this worked me. I appreciate  your time and help